# Include modules, which are not imported somewhere in the project, into next.js build

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, code-splitting

I came across a problem where I need to include and evaluate a module in a bundle which is not imported somewhere in a next.js application.

**Some Background information**

Im currently working to implement a Java-esque [Service Provider Interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi) pattern to register certain classes in typescript.
It is based around a class decorator which pushes the constructor of the wrapped class into a set.

```
// file: B.ts
@registerMe("classIdB")
class B {}

// file: C.ts
@registerMe("classIdC")
class C {}

// file: import.ts
const instance: C = getInstanceOf("classIdC") as C;
```

The big problem is now, that these decorated classes are not imported somewhere but instantiated dynamically on runtime. So i guess in the next.js or webpack build pipeline they get excluded or are not present in the first place.

What i tried so far:

**(1) write a webpack plugin which flags classes with a certain path as `used`, following [this implementation](https://github.com/i-like-robots/disable-tree-shaking-for-chunk-plugin/blob/master/src/plugin.js).**
( i thought treeshaking could be the problem, which it was not )

```
class DisableTreeShakingForModule {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = Object.assign({}, options)
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(PluginName, (compilation) => {
      compilation.hooks.afterOptimizeTree.tap(PluginName, (chunks, modules) => {
        const target = modules.filter((module) => module.resource && module.resource.includes("some-path/"))

        if(!target) return;
        target.forEach((m) => {
          m.used = true
          m.usedExports = true
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

**(2) Add a custom entry point to my webpack config in `next.config.js`**
( i thought i need to add those file as an extra entry point, but despite a bundle 'test' beeing created the files in it are not loaded and evaluated on runtime.

```
webpack(prevConfig, { dev, isServer }) {
  return Object.assign({}, config, { entry: function() {
    return config.entry().then((entry) => {
      return Object.assign({}, entry, {"test": glob.sync("some-path/*.tsx")})
    })
  }});
}
```

**(3) Idea: add these files to the next.js `common` bundle which is always imported** (but i don't know how to do that)